# Get Label For SObject API Name

Tags: apex, custom-object, describesobject, describes

I have an exhaustive list of custom objects whose API Names and labels does not match. I end up opening each object in order to determine if the label has matching API Name.I want to see the API Name displayed along with label on the result page of custom Objects. Is there a better way to get label for a custom object when its API Name is known?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the label using the `DescribeSObjectResult`:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.MyApiName__c;
system.debug(describe.getLabel());
```

Another common syntax is:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = MyApiName__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
```

You can also just one-line it:

```
system.debug(SObjectType.MyApiName__c.getLabel());
```

Comment: I am looking to do it from the platform, not from the code. A soql query will also help.

Comment: You cannot use a query. What do you mean by *from the platform*?

Comment: When I log into my org I do a search for objects which has more than 500 objects. I know the API Name and want to navigate to that object but I end of opening each object to see if that is the object I am looking for or not.

Comment: You are really not making yourself clear. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked how to handle an

> exhaustive list of custom objects

not just 1 at a time.

For built-in sObjects, the Label is *usually* the same as the API name but with spaces. Unfortunately there are exceptions for example

**API Name**: OpportunityLineItem
**UI Label**: Opportunity Product

Custom sObjects can be anything, so you'll need to get a map of all of their API names and Labels. Much of that comes out of the box with `Schema.getGlobalDescribe();`
The code below worked for me to put the API Name next to the Label.

```
    Map<String, SObjectType> sObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    for (String apiName : sObjects.keySet()) {
        // As far as I know all custom sObject API names end in __c   
        if (!sObjects.get(apiName).getDescribe().getName().endsWith('__c')) {
            // Replace spaces with empty string
            System.debug(sObjects.get(apiName).getDescribe().getName() + ' - ' + sObjects.get(apiName.replaceAll('\\s+', '')).getDescribe().getLabel());
        } else {
            System.debug(sObjects.get(apiName).getDescribe().getName() + ' - ' + sObjects.get(apiName).getDescribe().getLabel());
        }
    }
```

Now that the SFDX CLI is available however, I would install it and write a fake test that runs the code above and then [redirect it to the CLI](https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/03/14/streaming-apex-logs-to-your-console/).

From there, you could *further* redirect that output to a file, which would be pretty easy to convert to a basic HTML or VisualForce table.

You probably have the same issue with custom fields. There are now browser plugins for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sfdc-api-fieldnames/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-api-fieldnames/oghajcjpbolpfoikoccffglngkphjgbo?hl=en) which do an OK job of displaying the fields in **Classic Mode**